# Unexpected call to method or property access in IE7 and IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, appendchild

I am using jquery-1.3.2.min.js in my project.
My application is working fine in all browsers except IE7 and IE 8. 
It throws following error.

**SCRIPT65535: Unexpected call to method or property access. 
jquery-1.3.2.min.js, line 12 character 2305**

I have been looking for a solution but didn't get any proper solution.
please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks,

Atul Patel.

Comment: is there any reason to use ver 1.3.2? I recommend at least 1.6.2

Comment: what does line 12 look like? IE7 and 8 throw errors for all kinds of stupid reasons, can you give any more context?

Comment: @Sang Thanks for your reply. Actually I have user version 1.7.1 even same problem is raised. If i use 1.6.2 then it will resolve my issue?

Comment: @Sinetheta Line no 12 looks like **this.appendChild(E)**

Comment: @AtulPatel actually I'm using 1.6.1 for the webpage that I'm working on now and it works perfectly in IE7&8. is it jQuery itself's problem? and do not use minified version of jQuery before you publish it. you can not see beautiful well-coded jQuery source code if you use minified version.

Comment: @Sang I have placed 1.6.1 version. still facing same issue.

Comment: @AtulPatel use it: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.js and tell me in what line does it throw error.

Comment: @Sang I have placed your file in my project but still having same problem on line no-5569 **this.appendChild( elem );**

Comment: @AtulPatel are you using `$.extend` in your code?

Comment: @Sang No. I am not using this **$.extend** method.

Comment: @AtulPatel then it might comes from other plugins that you used. make empty page and load jQuery only, then you'll see.

Answer (score 11):

I have experienced this error too using jQuery 1.7.1.

The error was caused by myself! I used `.text("foo")` on an inputfield that used to be a `<span>`. So when I changed `.text("foo")` to `.val("foo")`, everything worked.

To find out what was causing the error, I started debugging, checking the callstack in the console everytime I stepped backwards.

Comment: I experienced the same in IE7 and IE8 when updating `.text()` on `$('.class')` when both spans and input elements have class="class". I changed this to be `$('.class:not(input)').text(...); $('input.class').val(...);`

Comment: @JoeBowman I ran into exactly the same thing. Thanks for saving me from several hours of banging my head against the wall.